# ¿Como puedo pasar un JSON a una tabla?

Tags: c#, mvc

espero me puedan apoyar con este tema

Tengo un Json y lo quiero mandar a una vista dentro de una tabla, siempre he usado Ajax para hacer el metodo POST y retorne hacia el success, pero ahora el post lo mando desde otra vista y quiero enviar el JSON a otra.

Y Cuando lo envia a mi vista aparece la pantalla en blanco y el JSON y no respeta mi layout.

[{"Consecutivo":2223,"Anexo":"A01   ","Factura":29556,"Saldo":155096.42}]

¿Como puedo mandarlo a una tabla o que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias por su ayuda

Controlador:

```
 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in DTResult.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in DTResult.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    return Json(rows);
                }
```

Vista

```
    <section class="content">
        <!-- Default box -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Facturas</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">

                <div id="Listado" name="Listado">
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>

    </section>


    @section Scripts
    {
    <script>
         var tabla = "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped' id='tblProvInt'>";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success:
                    function (data) {

                        tabla += "<thead><tr><th>Presamo</th><th>Anexo</th><th>No. Factura</th><th>Saldo</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            tabla += "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].Consecutivo
                                + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                + data[i].Anexo
                                + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                + data[i].Factura
                                + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                + data[i].Saldo
                                + "</td>"
                        }
tabla += "</tbody></table>";
                    tabla.replace("null", "");
                    $("#Listado").html(tabla);


</script>
```

Comment: generas la tabla pero nunca indicas quien contendra dicha tabla,  despues del for agrega document.getElementById("Listado").innerHTML = tabla;

Comment: Disculpa, no coloque esa parte, si la tengo, hago referencia a mi tabla. pero aun así no me crea la tabla y muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el valor `AllowGet` de la enumeración `JsonRequestBehavior` a el método `Json` en el controlador.
De forma predeterminada, los datos JSON solo se enviarán en respuesta a las solicitudes POST, pero al pasar este valor como parámetro al método `Json`, se le indica a MVC que responda también a las solicitudes GET.

Por Ejemplo

```
//Controlador
public JsonResult ObtenerDatos(){ 
    string[] datos = {
        "dato1",
        "dato2",
        "dato3"
    };
    return Json(datos,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}

//Solicitud GET
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success:function(data){
        //...
    }
});
```

Se debe utilizar `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` si los datos que se van a devolver no son privados. 
Debido a un problema de seguridad en muchos navegadores web, es posible que los sitios de terceros intercepten 
los datos JSON que se devuelven en respuesta a una solicitud GET, 
por lo que `JsonResult` no responderá a las solicitudes GET de forma predeterminada. 
En la mayoría de los casos, se debe utilizar solicitudes POST para recuperar los datos JSON en su lugar, evitando el problema.